# How to create a CGPath which exactly match a CALayer bounds when the layer rotate or scale?

Tags: ios, calayer, cgpath

We have a CALayer which shows image with edit information. Such as rotate, scale and translate. I want to make a CGPath which exactly match the layer bounds. When the layer rotate, my path should also rotate and its four corners should match the CALayer's four corners. The CGPath is actually used as a gray mask to show the clipped area of the image.

I try following code, but it does not work.

```
    f = self.imageLayer.frame;
    t = self.imageLayer.affineTransform;
    CGPathAddRect(path, &t, f);
```

The CALayer has its own CGAffineTransform. All edit information are applied via the CGAffineTransform.

Any hint will be appreciated, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right you could be using `UIBezierPath`'s [`usesEvenOddFillRule`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/usesEvenOddFillRule) to cut around your image layer bounds dimming the rest of the visible screen. Basically you create a very large rectangular path (for some reasons CGRectInfinite doesn't work here) and cut out the area around your image layer. The trick is to use `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd` which flips what is considered inside and outside.

Something like should work:

```
    let cutPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: imageLayer.bounds, cornerRadius: 0)

    let clipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(-10e6, -10e6, 10e7, 10e7)) // CGRectInfinite isn't working here ?
    clipPath.appendPath(cutPath)
    clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.1, green:0.1, blue:0.1, alpha:0.5).CGColor
    shape.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    shape.path = clipPath.CGPath
    imageLayer.addSublayer(shape)

    // do a transformations here
    imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(10.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
```

Which results

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I finally solved the issue. We have a fixed rectangle represent the clip area (Its size maybe is as 500 * 400). And the image outside it will be clipped. The clipped part of the image have a grey mask over it. When image rotate the mask will follow the image.
I use CGPathAddRect(path, &t, f); and other existing CGPathMoveToPoint, CGPathAddLineToPoint code to create the mask. We have offsetX and offsetY and size of the image layer. And I rotate the mask around (offsetX, offsetY) point. I think your add subLayer and kCAFillRuleEvenOdd tricks are very useful for me.